# OTRS: using SHA-256 algorithm for IMAPS sessions

Tags: email, ssl, imap, sha256, otrs

We are using OTRS, which receive mail through external mail provider via IMAPS.

Mail provider is going to stop supporting mail clients which use unsafe SHA-1 signing algorithm. To continue using this mail provider we must be sure that our OTRS uses exactly SHA-256 algorithm to sign certificates during IMAPS session.

How could I check, what signing algorithm is used for IMAPS? Where can i find configs for this?

OTRS: 4.0.13
OS: CentOS 7.1

Comment: IMAPS does not sign any kind of certificates. I think you are confusing various things here. Probably the ISP just said that their server certificate gets now signed with SHA-256 and that the IMAP client must support it. And unless you have a very very old version of OpenSSL on your system this should be no problem.